# Cointelation (hybrid method between COINTegration and corrELATION technique) on two series using R

Tags: r

Cointelation is a a hybrid method between COINTegration and corrELATION techniques.

Ref:

http://wilmott.com/pdfs/MVMC_CSL_05_2012.pdf

There are some great packages in R on cointegration but I could not find anything on cointelation on http://www.rseek.org/ or in http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/

I have two time series

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("YHOO",src="google") 

getSymbols("GOOG",src="yahoo")
```

How can I perform a cointelation on the two series using R?

Is there any package, functions, code or references in R dealing with cointelation?
I would be grateful for any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new article which came out october 23rd. It can be found here:
http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/wilm.10252/abstract

Comment: How is this answer relevant to the OP's question? Does the article contain R code? If so, please specify that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done some research before posting?

To do things manually:http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tsDyn/vignettes/ThCointOverview.pdf

Otherwise you can check the pair trading package.